# Where are Validator error messages stored in Laravel?

Tags: php, string, laravel, error-handling, laravel-validation

I have the following code in a blade file:

```
@if($errors->has('password_again'))
    <div class="error">
        * {{ $errors->first('password_again') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

This line:

```
{{ $errors->first('password_again') }}
```

Displays:

```
"The password again field is required."
```

However I can't seem to find this string anywhere. I've looked in the Controller file which calls this blade and just went through a ton of files searching for the string and can't seem to find it. Which file should I be looking in to edit this string?

EDIT:

I tried this it doesn't seem to do anything?

```
    $messages = [
        'password_again' => 'The confirm password field is required.',
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(),
        array(
            'email'             => 'required|max:50|email|unique:users',
            'username'          => 'required|max:30|min:3|unique:users',
            'password'          => 'required|min:8',
            'password_again'    => 'required|same:password'
        ),
        $messages
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

If needed, you may use custom error messages for validation instead of the defaults. There are several ways to specify custom messages.
Passing Custom Messages Into Validator

```
$messages = [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
];

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
```

**Specifying Custom Messages In Language Files**

In some cases, you may wish to specify your custom messages in a language file instead of passing them directly to the Validator. To do so, add your messages to custom array in the `resources/lang/xx/validation.php` language file.

Read more at:

> http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't seem to do anything? I've updated the question to reflect what I tried.

Comment: @rotaercz do you search the string in resources/lang/xx/validation.php language file. ?

Comment: Yeah, I did look in that file too. It's not there.

Comment: I appreciate the time and effort you put in to help. I'll keep looking. Thanks. I am using Laravel 4.2 if that makes a difference.